# Interrupt a running process with IPC

Tags: c#, multiprocessing, ipc

I have two processes in a Win Form application. In the first process I have a methode "checkIfTrue" which has a return value of boolean. The methode in the first process  will get some information from the second process by IPC (I use WCF with named pipes) and will return, depand on the information from the second process true or false.

My problem how can I interrupt the first process? The method in the first process ask the second process for information, when the second process got the information and will send back the result to the first process. In the first process the result will not be process before the methode "checkIfTrue" are finished.

The second process will call a method "synchronizeResults" via IPC and transfer the results. The methode "synchronizeResults" store the result in a ConcurrentDictionary. My plan was to stop the methode "checkIfTrue" in first process until the Dictionary is filled. But the methode "synchronizeResults" is not calling by IPC until methode "checkIfTrue" is finished.

Normally i would fire a event when the result are send back from process 2, but in this case I need the result before the methode is finished.

Comment: Well, it depends. In what context are your two processed running? Are they services, console apps. desktop apps, web apps, something else? What kind of network infrastructure exists between the two processes? What kind of IPC are you planning (something RESTful, WCF, something closer to the wire)? In general,  the process you want to "interrupt" needs to be *listening* for the interruption.  When the IPC message arrives, the listening code goes off and does something (possibly on a separate thread), and then responds appropriately.  How this dance should happen depends on your constraints

Comment: It is a Win-Form application and for IPC I use WCF with named pipes.

Comment: I will try the AutoResetEvent.

Comment: There are two processes involved here.  If the listener is an WinForms app, then, in your startup code (say the form's constructor or the end of InitializeComponent) start a WCF host, and instruct it to listen.  When a message arrives, just `Form.Invoke` some call on the form.  It won't "interrupt" processing, but it will cause the call to run the next time your app digs into the form's message loop (which should be good enough for you).

Comment: I solved it with AutoResetEvent. The first process ask for information. At that point I call autoResetEvent.WaitOne(). After I get the result I call autoResetEvent.Set().

Comment: But I also forgot to mark the CallbackSevice class with [CallbackBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]. When a callback is made from the service to client, only one thread is spawned because by default the concurrency mode is set to “single”.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason while it doesnt work was my CallbackService-Class. I had forgot to mark the class with

```
[CallbackBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)].
```

When a callback is made from the service to client, only one thread is spawned because by default the concurrency mode is set to “single”.

Here's [a link] (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsnotes/2013/09/18/wcf-callback-operations-are-invoked-sequentially/)